# Using Count() and Sum() correctly in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, sum

Ok, so I hope I can explain this question well enough, because I feel like this is going to be a tough one.

I have two tables I'm working with today. These look like:

```
@pset table (PersonID int, SystemID int, EntitlementID int, TargetID int)

@Connector table (TargetName varchar(10), fConnector bit)
```

The first table stores records that tell me, oh this person has this system, which is composed of these entitlements, whom have these targets. A little complicated, but stay with me. The second stores the TargetName and then whether or not that target has a connector in my not-so-theoretical system.

What I'm trying to do is merge these two tables so that I can see the target flag for each row in @pset. This will help me later as you'll see.

If each entitlement in a system has a connector to the target (the **flag is true** for all of them), then I'd like to know.

All the others should go into a different table.

This is what I tried to do, but it didn't work. I need to know where I went wrong. Hopefully someone with more experience than me will be able to answer.

```
-- If the count(123) = 10 (ten rows with SystemID = 123) and the sum = 10, cool.
select pset.*, conn.fConnector from @pset pset
inner join vuTargets vt
on vt.TargetID = pset.TargetID
inner join @conn conn
on  conn.TargetName = vt.TargetName
group by ProfileID, SystemRoleID, EntitlementID, TargetID, fConnector
having count(SystemID) = sum(cast(fConnector as int))
order by ProfileID
```

and

```
-- If the count(123) = 10 (ten rows with SystemID = 123) and the sum <> 10
select pset.*, conn.fConnector from @pset pset
inner join vuTargets vt
on vt.TargetID = pset.TargetID
inner join @conn conn
on  conn.TargetName = vt.TargetName
group by ProfileID, SystemRoleID, EntitlementID, TargetID, fConnector
having count(SystemID) <> sum(cast(fConnector as int))
order by ProfileID
```

Unfortunately, these do not work :(

**Edit**

[image]

Here is a screenshot showing the problem. Notice ProfileID 1599 has a SystemID of 1126567, but one of the entitlements doesn't have a connector! How can I get both of these rows into the second query? (above)

Comment: You are using columns in your queries that are not in your provided schema, such as `TargetObjectID`. Please post the correct schema.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to sanitize the query but missed that, should be good now.

Comment: so you want to find the `PersonId` and `SystemId` where every entitlement has all targets with an `fConnector` equal to 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your basic problem is that you're trying to roll up to two different record sets.
The initial set (the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses) is saying that you want one record for every difference in the set [ProfileId, SystemId, EntitlementId, TargetId, fConnector].
The second set (the `HAVING` clause) is saying that you want, for *every row in the inital set*, to compare it's `COUNT` of records with the `SUM` of the connections.  However, because you've asked for grouping down to the individual flag, this has the effect of getting a *single row* for *each* flag (assuming 1-to-1 relationships).  Effectively, you're saying - 'Hey, if this target has a connection?  Yeah, I want it'.

What you appear to *want* is a roll up to the `SystemId` value.  To do that, you will need to change your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses to only include the set [ProfileId, SystemId].  This will return only those rows (keyed from profile and system) who has all targets 'connected'.  You will *not* be able to see the individual entitlements, targets, and whether they are connected (you will be able to *infer* that they will all be/not be connected, however).

---

EDIT:

In the interests of full disclosure, here is how you'd get something similar to your original results set, where it lists all `EntitlementId`s and `TargetId`s:

```
WITH all_connections as (SELECT pset.ProfileId, pset.SystemRoleId
                         FROM @pset pset
                         INNER JOIN vuTargets vt
                         ON vt.TargetId = pset.TargetId
                         INNER JOIN @conn conn
                         ON conn.TargetName = vt.TargetName
                         GROUP BY pset.ProfileId, pset.SystemRoleId
                         HAVING COUNT(pset.SystemRoleId) 
                                                  = SUM(CAST(fConnector as INT)))

SELECT pset.*
FROM @pset pset
JOIN all_connections conn
ON conn.ProfileId = pset.ProfileId
AND conn.SystemRoleId = pset.SystemRoleId
```

This should get you a listing, down to the `TargetId`, of `ProfileId`/`SystemRoleId` keys where all `EntitlementId`s and `TargetId`s have a connection (or, flip the CTE `=` to `<>` for those where not all do).

Comment: Yes, you've explained it better than I could. I will give this a shot, hope it works!

Comment: @TommyFisk - I've added a query that will give you results similar in _display_ to your results set, but only displaying if your original criteria is matched.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** fixed my original queries, updated the description as well

You can split this up: first find the `TargetID`s that have an `fConnector` of 0.  Then find the `PersonID`, `SystemID` pairs that have any target equal to the ones you found.  Then select the relevant data: (this finds the `PersonID`, `SystemID` pair where at least  one entitlement does not have a connector to the target)

```
with abc as (
    select PersonID, SystemID
    from pset P
    where TargetID in (
        select TargetID
        from vuTargets V join connector C on V.TargetName = C.TargetName
        where C.fConnector = 0
        )
)
select P.PersonID, P.SystemID, P.EntitlementID, P.TargetID, C.fConnector
from pset P
    join abc on ((P.PersonID = abc.PersonID) and (P.SystemID = abc.SystemID))
    join vuTargets V on P.TargetID = V.TargetID
    join connector C on V.TargetName = C.TargetName
```

The query to find the `PersonID`, `SystemID` pairs where all entitlements have a connector to the target is similar:

```
with abc as (
    select PersonID, SystemID
    from pset P
    where TargetID in (
        select TargetID
        from vuTargets V join connector C on V.TargetName = C.TargetName
        where C.fConnector = 0
        )
)
select P.PersonID, P.SystemID, P.EntitlementID, P.TargetID, C.fConnector
from 
    pset P
    join abc on ((P.PersonID <> abc.PersonID) or (P.SystemID <> abc.SystemID))
    join vuTargets V on P.TargetID = V.TargetID
    join connector C on V.TargetName = C.TargetName
```

The difference is in the join with the temp table (`<>` vs `=`).  This is very similar to zero's answer, but doesn't use counts or sums.

Comment: -1 Except that effectively gets him his original results.  The tables joined to in the outer select are not used, as well.

Comment: @X-Zero I see the problem. Edited the query to fix it. Also updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, -1 removed.  Although, the `...<>... or ...<>...` feels counter-intuitive.  I'd more likely attempt to either change the CTE to use `NOT IN` (instead of `IN`), or use an `EXCEPTION JOIN` on it.  Somewhat personal preference, though.